# Facebook Display Name Options

Tags: facebook

Not a huge fan of Facebook, mainly due to the fact that your name is displayed very clearly next to everything you post, and as my name isn't very common, I don't like the idea of having it  displayed next to every post I make.

So in the past I've come up with so many false names and aliases to conceal my identity, when all I really want to do is have the freedom to post as myself, without the world knowing my real name - like on most other social networks.

So, I'm pretty sure the format for Facebook is that you sign up with a First Name, Middle Name and Last Name, and then have the ability to add something like a Nickname or Maiden Name, resulting in your display name being:

`First Middle Last (Nickname)` for example.

But I was wondering if there was a way to only display a selection of these names:

`First (Nickname)` . `First Middle`

Any ideas if this can be done? If not for your main profile, at least for leaving comments in groups or on pages?

Alternatively can you create an alias for groups and pages? This is especially relevant if your posting in groups that are sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

As stated on the [official Facebook help page](https://www.facebook.com/help/112146705538576):

> - The name on your profile should be the name that your friends call you in everyday life. This name should also appear on an ID or
>     document from our ID list.
> - **Nicknames can be used as a first or middle name if they're a variation of your authentic name (like Bob instead of Robert)**.
> - **You can also list another name on your account (example: maiden name, nickname, professional name)**.
> - Profiles are for individual use only. You can create a Page for a business, organization or idea.
> - Pretending to be anything or anyone isn't allowed.
>
> Note: If your name follows our standards and you're still having
>   trouble changing it, [find out
>   why](https://www.facebook.com/help/448505685205813).

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit confusing that you want the freedom to post as yourself, but you want to change your name.

- You can change your name and explain to Facebook why you are changing it.
- You can alternatively create a new  profile with the name you want to use and abandon the current profile (multiple profiles are not allowed).

Consider that there are many people on Facebook using the names of Star Trek characters!

Comment: Can you clarify how this addresses the OP's problem of managing the selection of names that FB displays?Per marikamitsos' [link to FB standards](https://facebook.com/help/112146705538576), it is against FB policy to *pretend* to be anything or anyone and OP's  name should also match their ID.